# Is it possible to use tkinter to create a a directory select dialogue which can also display the files in that directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to use `tkFileDialog` to create a directory select dialogue, but also can display the files in that directory which can only be seen, not selected.

```
from tkFileDialog import *
......
def select_dir(self):
    d = askdirectory()
    if d:
    ......
```

But it seems the `askdirectory()` can't display the files in the directory. Is it possible to use `askdirectory()` implement my requirement?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind, subclass `askdirectory` and re-implement method which shows folders/files in the window.

Comment: you will have to build own window with all elements.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the built-in dialogs in this way. They work as documented, and only as documented. You will need to build your own dialog from a `Toplevel` window and various other widgets.